# How do I extract the REST API ID and Resource ID from a serverless.yml file?

Tags: node.js, aws-serverless

I'm using the AWS updateIntegrationResponse function and need a way to dynamically get the restApiId and resourceId values from a serverless.yml file.  How do I go about doing this?

I've already looked through everything listed in the serverless.yml file I'm working with, and none of the fields there have either value stored in them.

Answer (score 0):

Serverless creates a CloudFormation stack with the name being in the format {yourServiceName}-{yourStage}. One of the outputs of this stack is the API ID of the REST API Gateway created by Serverless and you could acquire this in your script. With the API ID you could list the resources and try to find the correct one for your need through the CLI API.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `updateIntegrationResponse` but the most efficient way to do what you need could be to implement a small Serverless plugin to do this at deployment time. In the plugin you have access to the full CloudFormation stack created by Serverless and can find the IDs you need - Serverless tends to create predictable names for the resources based on the function names in your `serverless.yml`.